# Drupal Date repetition interval enheretance

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I need a global interval template for recurring events.
I am constructing a schedule management web app. I have a set of event happening periodically up certain moment in time. For example I a have a train schedules. They repeat them selves every week for certain winter or summer periods. Using Date module I would have to enter ending and beginning dates of let say summer period for **each** train route. 
What I want to do is to simply add a taxonomy term which would hold repetition interval with some holiday exclusions...

This more Drupal philosophy question yet I think that others had ran into similar issues before.
Maybe I am looking to this problem from a wrong angel could somebody could lend me fresh set of eyes.